# How to pass promise output as prop using mobx

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobx, mobx-react, state-management

In my App.js file I have the follow code:

```
  import stores from 'client/stores';
  ...
  ...
  render() {
     return (
        <Provider {...stores}>
          <SafeAreaView>
            <AppContainer />
          </SafeAreaView>
       </Provider>
     );
  }
```

I want to retrieve my data from backend and inject it in `AppContainer`. However it has to be retrieved asynchronously using a promise:

```
// client/stores/index.js

boardsService.retrieveBoards().then(boards => {
    // I need to store boards here 
})
```

Then inject boards into my `AppContainer`

```
export default
@inject('boards')
@observer
class AppContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     console.log(props.boards); 
  }

  render() {
     ...
  }
}
```

I tried this in stores/index.js:

```
async function connect() {
  const connection = await boardsService.retrieveBoards();
  if (connection) {
    return connection;
  }
  return null;
}

connect().then(boards => {
  exports.boards = boards;
});
```

But I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the issue - I've got nothing :p

Comment: It doesn't work to create an export dynamically at runtime. You could create a [data store](https://mobx.js.org/best/store.html) that sets it data asynchronously that you export right away.

Comment: Can you show content of stores/index.js, what exactly are you exporting? Your export object should look something like { boards: { ... } }. My guess is that you are exporting boards object directly, and when destructing it in Provider, you get boards properties as available stores to inject which is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Actions in Mobx has no returned value. They just change the observable properties. It doesn't matter the action is synchronous or asynchronous.

```
@observable boards = [];

boardsService.retrieveBoards().then(boards => {
 this.boards.replace(boards);
})
```

Second, You should dereference the observable property only in render function, not constructor.